# Pointer Division possible?

Tags: c, pointers

How can i divide and multiplicate 2 variables in C with Pointers?
I tried this:

```
int multiplicate(int *x,int *y)
{
*x**y;
}


int divide(int *x,int *y)
{
*x/*y;
}
```

Comment: What you got after running?

Comment: use parens!!! `(*x)*(*y)`!!!!

Comment: You should store the result somewhere.

Comment: why are you using pointers. all they contribute here is complexity (notation, conceptual picture) and bug vectors (they can be un-dereferencable). in short it's about as ungood an idea as ideas get.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `return` statement:

```
int multiplicate(int* x, int* y)
{
  return (*x) * (*y);
}


int divide(int *x,int *y)
{
  return (*x) / (*y);
}
```

Comment: Parenthesis are not necessary here as the dereferencing `*`-operator binds tighter then the multiplicating `*`-operator.

Answer (score 2):

Use `*x/(*y)` instead. Else it's interpreted as a multiline comment. And you forgot `return`

Answer (score 2):

Since the indirection operator has higher precedence that multiplication operator, parenthesis are not needed.

Simply adding some whitespace will do:

```
int multiplicate(int *x,int *y)
{
    return *x * *y;
}


int divide(int *x,int *y)
{
    return *x / *y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Pointer Division possible?

You do not try to devide pointers here, but as using the dereferencing `*`-operator, the values the pointers are pointing to are use.

However, as all examples given so far fully miss essential error checking, I propose the following approaches:

```
int multiply(int * pr, int * px, int * py)
{
  int result = 0; /* Be optimistic. */

  if (NULL == pr || NULL == px || NULL == py)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    result = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    *pr = *px * *py;
  }

  return result;
}

int devide(int * pr, int * px, int * py)
{
  int result = 0; /* Be optimistic. */

  if (NULL == pr || NULL == px || NULL == py)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    result = -1;
  }
  elseif (0 = *py)  /* Division by zero is not defined. */
  {
    errno = EDOM;
    result = -1;
  }     
  else
  {
    *pr = *px / *py;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Call those functions like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* The two functions above go here. */

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS;

  if (2 > argc)
  {
    fprintf("Missing or invalid arguments.\n");
    printf("Usage: %s x y\n", argv[0]);
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (EXIT_SUCCESS == result)
  {
    int x = atoi(argv[1]); /* Better use strtol here. */
    int y = atoi(argv[2]); /* Better use strtol here. */

    printf("Got x = %d and y = %d.\n", x, y);

    {
      int r;
      if (-1 == multiply(&r, &x, &y)
      {
        perror("multiply() failed");
      }
      else
      {
        printf("%d * %d = %d\n", x, y, r);
      }
    }

    {
      int r;
      if (-1 == multiply(&r, &x, &y)
      {
        perror("devide() failed");
      }
      else
      { 
        printf("%d / %d = %d\n", x, y, r);
      }
    }
  }

  return result; 
}
```

Finally a more sane approach would be to use pointers **only** where needed.

A possible approch modifying the above examples would look like this:

```
int multiply(int * pr, int x, int y)
{
  int result = 0; /* Be optimistic. */

  if (NULL == pr)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    result = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    *pr = x * y;
  }

  return result;
}

int devide(int * pr, int x, int y)
{
  int result = 0; /* Be optimistic. */

  if (NULL == pr)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    result = -1;
  }
  elseif (0 = y) /* Division by zero is not defined. */
  {
    errno = EDOM;
    result = -1;
  }     
  else
  {
    *pr = x / y;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Call those functions like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* The two functions above go here. */

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS;

  if (2 > argc)
  {
    fprintf("Missing or invalid arguments.\n");
    printf("Usage: %s x y\n", argv[0]);
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (EXIT_SUCCESS == result)
  {
    int x = atoi(argv[1]); /* Better use strtol here. */
    int y = atoi(argv[2]); /* Better use strtol here. */

    printf("Got x = %d and y = %d.\n", x, y);

    {
      int r;
      if (-1 == multiply(&r, x, y)
      {
        perror("multiply() failed");
      }
      else
      {
        printf("%d * %d = %d\n", x, y, r);
      }
    }

    {
      int r;
      if (-1 == multiply(&r, x, y)
      {
        perror("devide() failed");
      }
      else
      { 
        printf("%d / %d = %d\n", x, y, r);
      }
    }
  }

  return result; 
}
```